# Why does my Array output to my mysql database goes wrong?

Tags: php, html, mysql, json, database

Yesterday one stackoverflow user helped me to enter a json file to an array. It works fine but I got a wrong output if I want to enter my data to my database.
My data looks like this before I try to enter it to the database ->

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [nickname] => Honk [votes] => 10 ) [1] => Array ( [nickname] => NaryX [votes] => 10 )
```

That comes through this code ->

```
$json_string = $data;
$data_array = json_decode($json_string ,true);
print_r($data_array);
```

But if I try to enter my data it looks just like this:
[image]

This is the code for it ->

```
foreach($data_array as $data){
    $nickname = ($data['nickname']);
    $votes = ($data['votes']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO test (nickname, votes) VALUES ('$nickname', '$votes')";

    if (!mysqli_query($connbooster, $sql)) {
        echo 'Problem to enter your data into the Database...';
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific with your expected outcome/ what you have tried.

Comment: Try echoing out your `$sql` statement to see if it looks like what you expect.

Comment: What data types are `nickname` and `votes`?

Comment: @Kisaragi these came form a json script data that I posted down below

Comment: @aynber yes I tried, the data right after the foreach is the data that goes wrong into my database but I don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php

    $hostname="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $dbname="test";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
$data= Array('name' => 'Bloodhand [address]',  'ts.bloodhand.de [port]' => 0, 'month' => 201711, 'voters' => Array ( 0 => Array ( 'nickname' => 'Honk', 'votes' => 10 ), 1 => Array ( 'nickname' => 'NaryX' ,'votes' => 10 )));

    foreach($data['voters'] as $row) {
        $nickname = ($row['nickname']);
        $votes = ($row['votes']);

         $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO test (nickname, votes) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $nickname, $votes);
    $stmt->execute();


    }
```

This code worked for me. Inserted the values as it should in the database. The type of the field i set in my table for both nickname & votes is

```
varchar(255)
```

Updated the query with prepared statement

Comment: No that doesn't work for me because the array data is constantly updating. I got the data form a json file on a website! The array data was just a small example from the whole data with over 100 different users (nickname, votes).

Comment: I get that but the structure of the array should remain the same. I mean these code will insert in database 1 user or 1000 users. It's the same parsing.

Comment: The thing is that this line -> "$data= Array ( 0 => Array ( 'nickname' => 'Honk', 'votes' => 10 ), 1 => Array ( 'nickname' => 'NaryX' ,'votes' => 10 ));" just set the $data array to this 2 users but I need to add all users with changing amount of votes and nicknames to the database

Comment: But in your question you also retrieve the array and save it in the same format as i do in variable $data_array .  I just copied your array so i can have an input but my $data with your $data_array  are the same.

Comment: As i said if you add 1000 users in this code but the way you get them and insert them in the populated array is the same (so the array structure remains the same) all the users will be inserted successfully. There are nested arrays that are parsed inside the loop. The only think that i image that fails is that data escapes your sql query. try the sql query  i will update in my answer.

Comment: I post my new script with the same problem down below. I enter the new code into your code!

Comment: Updated my sql query. Try it that way because i think it escapes the parameters the one you are using (+ anyway it's dangerous to use it due to sql injection). Also check your db and let me know what type of fields you are using.

Comment: Now nothing happens ... :(  I post my mysql table and the whole output from json data !

Comment: Did you forgot your $sql entry in you updated code ?

Comment: The code should work. As i said the fields i am inserting data are both varchar. In case you have different fields in the bind_param step you must assign your variable type there. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

take a look at this guide. Also made a small update in the code.

Comment: Okay, first of all, yes your script works! BUT: you have the line with $data. Your variable is    $data= Array ( 0 => Array ( 'nickname' => 'Honk', 'votes' => 10 ),   BUT I need to enter my variable $data_array inside and my data comes from a different website with (file_get_contents). So I can not enter every single data it must work with the data I postet down below in "Whole output"

Comment: So if you can do it that my Array works with you script we are done. Thats all I want the whole time.

Comment: Ok so the data you wanted is another nested array. I updated my answer with the new array you provide me.

Comment: By the way your problem is parsing the array not insert data in the db. So it's just nested array read my code how i deal with this issue and understand what i am doing. I think it will be more helpful to you also for future projects. Let me know if you have any questions i will be glad to explain.

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help me !!! But the $data is wrong again the data (I can not edit the data) comes from an api from another website ! So it looks like this -> (last post on this thread). And my array needs to work with this informations !

Comment: As i said in my previous question in my code i saw you how to parse an array the right way. So have a look and try do it yourself. Take my example as a guide and adjust it into your array-response. I am pretty sure it will work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158770/discussion-between-philipp-hoerig-and-pr1nc3).

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = file_get_contents($filename);
$json_string = $data;
$data_array = json_decode($json_string ,true);
print_r($data_array );
foreach($data_array as $row) {
    $nickname = ($row['nickname']);
    $votes = ($row['votes']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO test (nickname, votes) VALUES ('$nickname', '$votes')";

    if (!mysqli_query($connbooster, $sql)) {
        echo 'Problem to enter your data into the Database...';

    }
}
```

Output -> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Whole a output ->

```
   Array ( [name] => Bloodhand [address] => ts.bloodhand.de [port] => 0 [month] => 201711 [voters] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [nickname] => Honk [votes] => 10 ) [1] => Array ( [nickname] => khemax [votes] => 10 ) [2] => Array ( [nickname] => Aciid [votes] => 10 ) [3] => Array ( [nickname] => NaryX [votes] => 10 ) [4] => Array ( [nickname] => Rici [votes] => 10 ) [5] => Array ( [nickname] => LordToto [votes] => 10 ) [6] => Array ( [nickname] => Hasso [votes] => 10 ) [7] => Array ( [nickname] => Ghost [votes] => 10 ) [8] => Array ( [nickname] => dieeeeeeter [votes] => 9 ) [9] => Array ( [nickname] => LosBastos [votes] => 9 ) [10] => Array ( [nickname] => Lindwurm [votes] => 9 ) [11] => Array ( [nickname] => Pedda [votes] => 9 ) [12] => Array ( [nickname] => hekker1337 [votes] => 9 ) [13] => Array ( [nickname] => Yosa [votes] => 9 ) [14] => Array ( [nickname] => LK|PYOGENESiS [votes] => 9 ) [15] => Array ( [nickname] => Brilliantix [votes] => 9 ) [16] => Array ( [nickname] => MadMan [votes] => 9 ) [17] => Array ( [nickname] => Kashtima [votes] => 9 ) [18] => Array ( [nickname] => Mysaty [votes] => 8 ) [19] => Array ( [nickname] => flausch [votes] => 8 ) [20] => Array ( [nickname] => aricos80 [votes] => 8 ) [21] => Array ( [nickname] => +moep+ [votes] => 8 ) [22] => Array ( [nickname] => C0kkie [votes] => 8 ) [23] => Array ( [nickname] => Lonium [votes] => 8 ) [24] => Array ( [nickname] => spast1337 [votes] => 7 ) [25] => Array ( [nickname] => markdieter [votes] => 7 ) [26] => Array ( [nickname] => †.-Gigi-.† [votes] => 7 ) [27] => Array ( [nickname] => Kosh [votes] => 7 ) [28] => Array ( [nickname] => Wizzl [votes] => 7 ) [29] => Array ( [nickname] => Jonas [votes] => 7 ) [30] => Array ( [nickname] => 76561198108442262 [votes] => 6 ) [31] => Array ( [nickname] => Bremi [votes] => 6 ) [32] => Array ( [nickname] => qtarndt [votes] => 6 ) [33] => Array ( [nickname] => Mensch [votes] => 6 ) [34] => Array ( [nickname] => Sunny [votes] => 6 ) [35] => Array ( [nickname] => hotzenkotz [votes] => 6 ) [36] => Array ( [nickname] => LittleFlight61 [votes] => 6 ) [37] => Array ( [nickname] => hawkk [votes] => 6 ) [38] => Array ( [nickname] => Lauk [votes] => 6 ) [39] => Array ( [nickname] => Copii [votes] => 5 ) [40] => Array ( [nickname] => eLy. [votes] => 5 ) [41] => Array ( [nickname] => rayD [votes] => 5 ) [42] => Array ( [nickname] => artur [votes] => 4 ) [43] => Array ( [nickname] => Beasted [votes] => 4 ) [44] => Array ( [nickname] => Luxh [votes] => 4 ) [45] => Array ( [nickname] => BD Freddy [votes] => 4 ) [46] => Array ( [nickname] => hansottobaum [votes] => 4 ) [47] => Array ( [nickname] => donut [votes] => 4 ) [48] => Array ( [nickname] => Rauler alias Andy [votes] => 4 ) [49] => Array ( [nickname] => Alannah [votes] => 4 ) [50] => Array ( [nickname] => Phyenty [votes] => 3 ) [51] => Array ( [nickname] => Dati [votes] => 3 ) [52] => Array ( [nickname] => EnOra [votes] => 3 ) [53] => Array ( [nickname] => HerrLehmann [votes] => 3 ) [54] => Array ( [nickname] => Sphere [votes] => 3 ) [55] => Array ( [nickname] => 76561198201725559 [votes] => 3 ) [56] => Array ( [nickname] => Poirot [votes] => 3 ) [57] => Array ( [nickname] => Philipp [votes] => 3 ) [58] => Array ( [nickname] => Ralf029 [votes] => 3 ) [59] => Array ( [nickname] => Flotti T_T [votes] => 3 ) [60] => Array ( [nickname] => Marcel [votes] => 3 ) [61] => Array ( [nickname] => Vergesslicher [votes] => 3 ) [62] => Array ( [nickname] => Achilles [votes] => 3 ) [63] => Array ( [nickname] => marcusnbg [votes] => 2 ) [64] => Array ( [nickname] => Boutscher [votes] => 2 ) [65] => Array ( [nickname] => Trinity333 [votes] => 2 ) [66] => Array ( [nickname] => opastine [votes] => 2 ) [67] => Array ( [nickname] => philsnetz [votes] => 2 ) [68] => Array ( [nickname] => Christoph1990 [votes] => 2 ) [69] => Array ( [nickname] => Tsumi89 [votes] => 2 ) [70] => Array ( [nickname] => kroesch [votes] => 2 ) [71] => Array ( [nickname] => flexrecords [votes] => 2 ) [72] => Array ( [nickname] => DJschatz27 [votes] => 2 ) [73] => Array ( [nickname] => sniff [votes] => 2 ) [74] => Array ( [nickname] => StoneBase [votes] => 2 ) [75] => Array ( [nickname] => Offensivkrieger [votes] => 2 ) [76] => Array ( [nickname] => MiniG4mer [votes] => 2 ) [77] => Array ( [nickname] => CeLiFiG [votes] => 2 ) [78] => Array ( [nickname] => Dhaimos [votes] => 2 ) [79] => Array ( [nickname] => Chucky [votes] => 2 ) [80] => Array ( [nickname] => >Maik< [votes] => 1 ) [81] => Array ( [nickname] => Successfully [votes] => 1 ) [82] => Array ( [nickname] => DannyBoy [votes] => 1 ) [83] => Array ( [nickname] => dalewilson [votes] => 1 ) [84] => Array ( [nickname] => du [votes] => 1 ) [85] => Array ( [nickname] => iRezZix [votes] => 1 ) [86] => Array ( [nickname] => imed [votes] => 1 ) [87] => Array ( [nickname] => HuLord [votes] => 1 ) [88] => Array ( [nickname] => DVC [votes] => 1 ) [89] => Array ( [nickname] => GYJohn [votes] => 1 ) [90] => Array ( [nickname] => Walle_NET [votes] => 1 ) [91] => Array ( [nickname] => Sorou [votes] => 1 ) [92] => Array ( [nickname] => Wayne3 [votes] => 1 ) [93] => Array ( [nickname] => Stareex [votes] => 1 ) [94] => Array ( [nickname] => Der Hauptmann [votes] => 1 ) [95] => Array ( [nickname] => Schaakiri [votes] => 1 ) [96] => Array ( [nickname] => RiT [votes] => 1 ) [97] => Array ( [nickname] => LouisB [votes] => 1 ) [98] => Array ( [nickname] => Mad0ck [votes] => 1 ) [99] => Array ( [nickname] => kyax [votes] => 1 ) ) )
```

Mysql table -> [image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this

`Array ( [name] => Bloodhand [address] => ts.bloodhand.de [port] => 0 [month] => 201711 [voters] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [nickname] => Rici [votes] => 10 ) [1] => Array ( [nickname] => NaryX [votes] => 10 )`

But you wrote it like this

> -> `'name' => 'Bloodhand [address]',  'ts.bloodhand.de [port]' =>
>
> > 0, 'month' => 201711, 'voters' => Array ( 0 => Array ( 'nickname' =>
> >     'Honk', 'votes' => 10 ), 1 => Array ( 'nickname' => 'NaryX' ,'votes'
> >     => 10 ))`

and I can't edit these informations because they came from another website !